# Как определить источнк "писателя" syslog-ng

Tags: linux, сеть, ip, логирование, protocol

Всем привет.
Есть хост,  на этот хост по ip летят данные(логи) с роутера. 
На хосте работает syslog-ng , который записывает в файл все, что пришло.
P.S Роутер в логе не пишет свои данные.

Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Можно ли как то идентифицировать отправителя на сервере, например, по Ip, если да, то как? или может есть другие методы?

Будет полезен любой совет! Спасибо

Comment: почти наверняка возможно, у меня в `rsyslog`'е сбор отдельных сообщений от отдельных хостов настроен [так](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/9rkulF2OLGAOQzSzz7UY/). Для syslog-ng навскидку не скажу как, но там где-то в назначение должно быть возможно указать... Если дашь пример своего конфига и как именно хочешь распределять логи, скорей всего что-нибудь смогу набросать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fat-Zer, спасибо за подсказку, чуть больше гугления и я нашел ответ:
$FULLHOST_FROM - поазывает IP адрес отправителя.

```
`destination sec_log { file('/var/log/$FULLHOST_FROM.log'); }; #создает файл (точку назначения)`
```